# Nonlinear least squares error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to fit some data to a nonlinear equation in MATLAB. I am using the package lsqnonlin. I cannot seem to find out why I am getting an error in my estimation. My code looks as follows:

```
fun = @(x)x(1)*log(x(2)/v)-y;
x0 = [15,15];
lb = [15,15];
ub = [1000,1000];
options = optimoptions('lsqnonlin','Display','iter');
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output] = lsqnonlin(fun,x0,lb, ub, options)
x
```

where v is my data. V ranges from 0.2 to ~14, so I set the lower bound to 15 so my function would always be defined. However, when I run the program I still get an error stating that the objective function is returned undefined values at initial point.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you give exact values for `v` and `y` that reproduce your error, and give the error itself.

Comment: As Phil had mentioned, please make sure your question contains a [mcve], otherwise you are risking it being closed as off-topic (for a couple of different reasons).